Can't access internet after changing the router
I have a desktop running proxmox that I can ssh into. After moving houses and changing the router, I stopped being able to ssh into it. After connecting it to a monitor and keyboard to troubleshoot the problem. I noticed that it can't reach the internet and I can't ping anything in it. It's worth noting that this proxmox server is running a VM. Interestingly, I can ssh into the VM and it reaches the internet. Just the proxmox server or host OS can't reach anything. See some more info:
root@pve:~# ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.30 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.30 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.30 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

root@pve:~# ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev vmbr0 proto kernel onlink
192.168.1.0/24 dev vmbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.30

root@pve:~# ip link show vmbr0
4: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 74:56:3c:58:26:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


are the old and new networks on the same subnets?

Idk is there a way to figure this out? I don't have access to the old network ofc

the settings for the proxmox server is that for the old network. Check the new network and make them match - that the VM works is likely to be helpful here your old network is on 192.168.1.x - commonly consumer gear uses that or 0.x

I think you are right, the vm has the ip 192.168.100.33 and it uses the default gateway of 192.168.100.1. But how do I move my proxmox server's network configuration to the new network?

Proxmox is on a static IP, and trying to connect to the 'old' subnet and the guest is bridged and picking up an IP from the connected network's DHCP server. The old and new networks are be on different subnets and the bridged network adaptor in the VM somehow works, but the proxmox host is on an invalid IP and you can't connect to it.
Check the IP range of the 'new' network and ensure the proxmox server's network settings are valid for the new network - things like default gateway and the IP ranges, and the proxmox servers' IP is not already taken.
I suspect 'easy mode' here would be to change the IP address range of your new router to the old one - you've mentioned the old one was in a fairly common 192.168.1.x range, and the new one's 192.168.100.1 range. This is out of the scope of my answer and be sure to remember to make sure resetting the router is an option should you have issues.
Else you can edit the settings on the proxmox box in order to update the ip address settings
Now, the tricky part is you need access to the proxmox box - and you need to connect to the proxmox box somehow with 'broken' networking. I believe you can just install a monitor and keyboard directly to the box and log in as root
Alternatively you can ssh in, and edit files directly, it would be one option.You need a physical box, set up with a static IP with the same range as the old system so you can SSH in or access it via a web UI. This is probably easier
Once you've done that  either approach would let you edit config files and get you to a usable state- the guide here's handy, and I'll point out the specific things you need to do
In the shell, you need to use nano, or the text editor of your choice, and edit /etc/networks/interfaces from what it was to something like
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.100.30/24
        gateway 192.168.100.1
        bridge-ports eno1
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
  

Essentially, just change the IPs from old to new.
You will also need to edit /etc/hosts to reflect the new IP.
While restarting some services would do (networks for example), I'd suggest rebooting, then checking through to ensure things work.

I think you are right, the vm has the ip 192.168.100.33 and it uses the default gateway of 192.168.100.1. But how do I move my proxmox server's network configuration to the new network?

updated my answer

Perfect, thanks a lot! This fixed my problem. Additionally, I had to modify nameserver entry in /etc/resolve.conf as it was pointing to the old gateway.
